# Stacking linux folder contents to appear as one folder

Tags: linux, directory, hyperlink

Does anyone know if there's anyway to make the contents of one folder to appear as just one, through pointers or links or something? So for example if in Linux I have folders like

```
/home/2012/
/home/2011/
/home/2010
....
/home/1990/
```

What what I'm wondering if it is possible to "stack" all the contents to appear as if they're all in one folder

```
/home/masterlist/
```

I was wondering if through creating links or some way. Do you know if that's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a directory `/masterlist/`
2. cd into that directory
3. run this command:

   ```
   find ../[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
   ```

Comment: So that command worked but I noticed that it makes a link for every file. So if a file is added to a directory the masterlist directory won't see that file unless the script is ran again where it would pick it up and make a link. Is there anyway to just link the directory's contents so anytime a new file is added the master list will automatically pick it up

Comment: @MichaelBlack if you want it to be up to date whenever directories are modified, look into one of the other answers using UnionFS

Answer (score 0):

you could also try something like UnionFS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unionfs

Comment: I'd upvote this if it went into any kind of detail about what UnionFS is.  Wikipedia links aren't answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably some kind of Union Filesystem. Look here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS

Actually  this is quite advance feature, if you like it, you may be interested with "Plan 9" OS subject :-)